# PostgreSQL how to see particular query have run or not

Tags: postgresql

I have `Postgres` db. My `NodeJs` application connects it and runs a job every 30 minutes. In that job it runs a query.

I want to check, that query is actually running or not after every 30 minutes. How can I check a particular query runs or not in `Postgres DB`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `log_min_duration_statement = 0` parameter, the PostgreSQL log will indicate when the query has finished running.  Also, if you wish to print the query when it is about to start running, you can use `log_statement = 'all'`

The way to set these parameters would be simply by calling:

```
> ALTER SYSTEM SET log_min_duration_statement to 0;
ALTER SYSTEM
> ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement to 'all';
ALTER SYSTEM
> SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Note that it is possible for these two parameters to produce a lot more log traffic and take up disk space, so use at your own risk.

More information about logging can be [found in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state='active' AND query='{your query}';
```

You can see query_start, state_change or even if it has a LOCK on wa
Additional, you can filter by other fields like "username", "client_hostname","client_addr", etc...

More info: [PostgreSQL doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW)

You can put the statement in a function in which you can decide what to do with the queries that are running for longer than 30 min.